# Ngix 403 Forbidden - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

My nginx keep throwing 403

I opened up the log, I see this

> 2019/10/23 12:08:25 [error] 28945#28945: *18 directory index of "/home/bheng/snake-river/public/" is forbidden, client: 20.231.19.250, server: default, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "167.99.234.85"

Then I went into my VM I ran this

```
chgrp www-data public/
service nginx reload
```

and now see this

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     www-data 4.0K Oct 23 12:15 public/
```

Refresh the page still the same ‍♂️

```
http://167.99.234.85/
```

**ps -ef | grep nginx**

```
root     29332     1  0 12:15 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
root     29369 29164  0 12:16 pts/2    00:00:00 tail -f /var/log/nginx/default-error.log
www-data 29769 29332  0 12:40 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root     29771 29278  0 12:42 pts/3    00:00:00 grep nginx
```

---

**sudo ufw app list**

```
Available applications:
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSH
```

---

I also tried `$uri` and `$uri/`

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
}
```

and

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
}
```

Same result

---

## nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Incorrect file permissions are another cause of the "403 Forbidden" error. The standard setting of **755** for directories and **644** for files is recommended for use with NGINX. The NGINX user also needs to be the owner of the files.

**Identify the NGINX User**

To begin, you will need to determine what user NGINX is running as. To do this, use the command:

```
ps -ef | grep nginx
```

Check the first column, for any of the NGINX worker processes:

In this example, the NGINX worker process is running as the user nginx.

**Set File Ownership**

Go to the directory above the website's document root. For example, if your website's document root is **/usr/share/nginx/example.com** go to **/usr/share/nginx** with the command:

```
cd /usr/share/nginx
```

Change the ownership of all the files from this point down to the nginx user with the command:

```
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx
```

**Set Permissions**

Set the permissions of each directory at this location to **755** with the command:

```
sudo chmod 755 [directory name]
```

For example, to set the permissions of the **example.com** directory, the command is:

```
sudo chmod 755 example.com
```

Then go to the web document root directory:

```
cd example.com
```

Change the permissions of all the files in this directory with the command:

```
sudo chmod 644 *
```

> https://www.ionos.com/community/server-cloud-infrastructure/nginx/solve-an-nginx-403-forbidden-error/